# Rewrites on .htaccess for WordPress and React Router Frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

For my current project, I am using a React frontend and a WordPress app as a backend. This is mostly functional, except for one problem:

**When accessing a specific route of the site directly (not from the homepage) or when refreshing, the URL is not found.**

Meaning if I go to mysite.org everything works fine. I can access other routes with the navigation on the site. But if I type in mysite.org/contact, it 404s. The same thing happens if I refresh on anything other than the homepage.

I suspect this is because of how my .htaccess is configured. I've seen other posts regarding React router and .htaccess that are fixed with rewrite rules, but those solutions did not work for me since I still need the WordPress rewrite rules to be present. I'm new to Apache and editing .htaccess, so forgive me if this is simple.

As far as I understand, I just need all WordPress calls to go to the index.php, and everything else to the React index.html.

**Here is the relevant snippet of my current .htaccess setup:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#Ideally, what is below would route any non-WordPress routes to the React app. 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

**The server's root directory is like this:**

/ (root directory)

--wp/ (wordpress folder. mysite.org/wp/wp-admin accesses the admin site.)

--.htaccess

--index.html   (the built React app)

--index.php

**Here is my React Router:**

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Home banners={banners} blurbs={blurbs}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='' element={<Home banners={banners} blurbs={blurbs}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/about/leadership' element={<AboutLeadPage stafflist={staff}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/about/youth' element={<AboutYouthPage youthposts={youthPosts}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/about/beliefs' element={<AboutBeliefsPage beliefs={beliefs}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/about/who-we-are' element={<WhoWeArePage/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/about/what-to-expect' element={<WhatToExpectPage/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/missions' element={<Missions missionslist={missions}/>}></Route>
  <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact/>}></Route>
</Routes>
```

Please let me know if you have any other questions/need more info.

Thank you!!

Comment: From your directory structure, WordPress would appear to be installed in the `/wp` subdirectory. However, the WP front-controller (ie. `index.php`) would appear to be in the document root, not `/wp/index.php`?

Comment: Yes - the root index.php simply points any relevant request to the initialization .php files in the WordPress app.